# Image filenames with white space

Tags: php

I get an array of image URL by php scanning image folders. Some of the image file names have white space. The part after white space got lost. for example:
This file is fine:

```
http://domain.com/folder/blue-sky.png
```

This file will lost the part sky.png

```
http://domain.com/folder/blue sky.png
```

My code for scanning the folder has nothing to do with checking or manipulating file names. How can I get the full name of  `blue sky.png` without rename it to `blue-sky.png`?

Comment: Please post the code you're using.

Comment: You can add a [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) line in your code for scanning the folder to take care of that issue.

Comment: Using `glob` I can't reproduce what you're saying. Please post your code

Comment: sorry for response late, I had power failure due to storm here after posting question. Thanks helping!

Comment: after apply urlencode($url), the url can't find my files. str_replace %20 solved the problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Space in url encoding are represented with the string "%20"
so you may want to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace every instance of the " " character to the character "%20"

```
echo str_replace(' ', '%20', 'http://domain.com/folder/blue sky.png');
```

will output

```
http://domain.com/folder/blue%20sky.png
```

---

**Complementary information**

Also, I never used it myself, but I would take a look at the php function [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) if I were you, it may contains useful information

Note : Url encode will transform every characters that is not standard of the string (so you may want to only use urlencode on the string that is your image name)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem but after experimenting with the answers above I realised that the real problem was that I had written my html link without the inverted commas - typically browsers are tolerant of this, but not if spaces are present.
i.e I had coded something like
a href=../folder/blue sky.png
instead of
a href="../folder/blue sky.png"
With the correct syntax spaces in the address do not cause problems

Comment: This also prevents saving of downloaded files with names like blue%20sky.png, hence should be the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use regex.

try;

```
$file_name = "http://domain.com/folder/blue sky.png";
$file_name2 = preg_replace("/ /", "-", $file_name);
echo $file_name2; //echos http://domain.com/folder/blue-sky.png
```

hope this helps...