# PHP Implode not creating array that I am hoping for

Tags: php, html

The distinguishing part of a media file name is missing after my php implode of an array that is built off a user post that is derived from a select multiple field.

Here is what the media file names look like when selected by the user:

```
September 2017 Rev10.png
September 2017 Rev11.png
September 2017 Rev12.png
```

Here is my implode function:

```
$media= $_POST["userMedia"];
$media_names = "'".implode( "','", $media)."%'";
```

Here is a dump of what they now look like:

```
"'September%','September%','September%'"
```

Here is what I need them to look like:

```
"'September 2017 Rev10.png','September 2017 Rev11.png','September 2017 Rev12.png'
```

Can anyone outline how I can correct my implode function to return the full file name?

Thanks

Select Statement for Multiple File Names:

```
SELECT 
m.name 
FROM
public.medias m

WHERE
m.name like '%Rev%.png';
```

Select statement using Posted media file array:

```
SELECT
m.name,
date (b.starttime),
Count(distinct(b.playerid)) as Stores

FROM
public.billing b,
public.medias m

WHERE
b.mediaitemid = m.id and
m.name LIKE any (array[$media_names]) and
b.starttime >= date('$datea') and 
b.starttime < date('$datez')+1

GROUP BY
m.name,
date (b.starttime)

ORDER BY
date (b.starttime);
```

Comment: how it can be that `2017 Rev12.png` is missing from the implode. your `dump` must be wrong

Comment: The output you've given can't possibly be the product of the input you've stated and the code you've posted. I'll wager that `$_POST['userMedia']` doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST["userMedia"]);`

Comment: var dump = "'September','September','September%'"

Comment: @KevMoe What is that percentage for? You include it in the concatenation but don't include it in your expected output?

Comment: The % was a wildcard that was held-over from where I sourced the code for this function. I removed it and used the suggestion from Sman Woll below and the dump was this: "'September','September','September'" Which makes me think that the spaces in the file names may be an issue.

Comment: Can you confirm if this line works: `$media_names = "'".str_replace(" ", "%20", implode( "','", $media))."'";`? Taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742601/3578036). Also ensure the form name is `name="userMedia[]"` but I think you did that.

Comment: Show your multiple select. Probably a quote issue.

Comment: Added multiple select to to question.

Comment: JustCarty, that resulted in the same array as before.

Answer (score 2):

If `$media` is an array of file names, this will work:

```
$media = ['September 2017 Rev10.png', 'September 2017 Rev11.png', 'September 2017 Rev12.png'];
echo "'" . implode("','", $media) . "'";
```

Comment: I used your suggestion and it returned this..."'September','September','September'" Which makes me think that the spaces in the file names may be an issue.